# How to do subdomain to subpath redirect / url rewrite in Next.js?

Tags: redirect, next.js, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have this rewrite in `next.config.js`:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: 'https://:postOrProgramId*.tikex-dev.com/',
            destination: 'https://tikex-dev.com/:postOrProgramId*',
        },
    ]
},
```

But it does not work.

I would do rewrite like this `amazing-campaign-in-nyc.tikex-dev.com` -> `tikex-dev.com/amazing-campaign-in-nyc`

Unfortunatelly when I run locally, I got this error, though I know it does not support localhost now.

```
`source` does not start with / for route {"source":"https://:postOrProgramId*.tikex-dev.com/","destination":"https://tikex-dev.com/:postOrProgramId*"}
```

Yes, `source` does not starts with `/` as I would expect first the protocol and then subdomain name comes. Is protocol + subdomain name not part of the `source`?

I am not sure, I need `:` before the variable and `*` after it? How can I express subdomain to subpath redirect?

I have an other reverseproxy rewrite. Do I have to worry about the two will interfere?

```
{
    source: '/api/:path*',
    destination: `${
        true
            ? `https://api.tikex-${
                    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT ?? 'dev'
              }.com/`
            : 'http://localhost:8080/'
    }:path*`,
},
```

Comment: _"Is protocol + subdomain name not part of the source?"_ - No, it is not. The rewrite is applied on whatever domain (or subdomain) your app is running on, so you can only define what path the rewrite rule will match against. What domain/subdomain is your Next.js app running on?

Comment: The domain has this structure `custom-sub-domain.tikex-dev.com`. `custom-sub-domain` can have any sub-string separated with `-`. I would 'translate', convert `custom-sub-domain` into subpath. Maybe it is only possible with middleware?